# update DateTime value in Table using SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

How can we update datetime value in a column using sql

say, if we want to update any of datetime values by adding an hour or 5 minutes etc.

```
UPDATE TableLastCalls
SET [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] =  ?? // want to add an hour
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function:

```
UPDATE TableLastCalls
SET [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] = DATEADD(hour, 1, [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME])
```

This will add 1 hour. Use `DATEADD(minute, 5, [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME])` instead to add 5 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [DATEADD](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/da-db_5.htm) function.

```
UPDATE TableLastCalls
SET [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] =  DATEADD(hour, 1, [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME])
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE TableLastCalls
SET [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] = DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, NEXT_UPDATE_TIME)

UPDATE TableLastCalls
SET [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] = DATEADD(HOUR, 2, NEXT_UPDATE_TIME)
```

and so on - lots of options with DATEADD to add specific amounts of time to your date.

See the [MSDN docs on DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for all the details.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE TableLastCalls
SET [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME] = DATEADD(hh, 1, [NEXT_UPDATE_TIME])
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dateadd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
update TableLastCalls
set NEXT_UPDATE_TIME = dateadd(hh, 1, NEXT_UPDATE_TIME)
```